# How to change payment accepted email subject in Prestashop 1.5.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

I am using Prestashop 1.5.6 . In this the email subject of Payment accepted email shows in english on all the languages. How to change the email subject of Payment accepted email ?.

Comment: To translate emails go to Localization > Translation, under Modify translations select Email templates translations and and search for the email you want to translate

Answer (score 1):

Order status e-mail subjects can't be edited straight from the e-mail templates.

You can change all the order status message translations under the Orders -> Statuses menu. Just choose Payment Accepted and add the translation in the status name field.